# Problem with CUPS on Ubuntu 14.04.3 amd-64

Tags: wine, printing, 64-bit, pdf

I use a business app, which I installed in Wine in my 64-bit system. I have to print reports from that app, so I have installed cups-pdf. However, after printing to PDF, I'm having these multi-colored rectangular regions on my PDF document (screenshot provided). I have tried the same app on my 32-bit system through Wine and there cups-pdf produced perfectly fine PDF documents. I tried using cups-boomaga, but the problem doesn't disappear.

My question is, is there any alternative to CUPS for 64-bit systems? Moreover, if CUPS is the best there is, is there a way to install the i386 version of CUPS in my 64-bit system?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=172796#p1009080

It provides separate printers for different output quality (different image resolutions, grayscale, etc.), asking you where to store the result.

It refers to Linux Mint, which is based on Ubuntu and so should work there, too.